# Parse email to unique text

Tags: email, indexing, awk, mbox

I have a large mailbox in the mbox format.  It is all articles so the header info isn't to relevant (except for the date).

What I want is to take my large *.mbx file and produce text files where the filename is the subject of each email and all the headers are removed.

I think AWK can do this with regular expressions but this sort of thing is not my area of expertise (more of a gui person).

My hope is that I can keep the files on my hard drive in less disk space and can finally index with Google Desktop Search.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to set the record separator variable to the empty string. That will read the file in "paragraph" mode.

```
awk -v RS="" '
    /^From / {
        # this $0 contains the email headers, grab the subject
        subject = "no subject"
        split($0, headers, /\n/)
        for (idx in headers)
            if (headers[idx] ~ /^Subject: /) {
                subject = headers[idx]
                sub(/^Subject: /, "", subject)
            }

        next
    }
    { print > subject}
' large.mbox
```

If you have emails with the same subject, the message bodies will be concatenated into one file.

I wouldn't expect to see a great amount of disk usage savings from this. You'll remove the headers, but increase the number of disk blocks required.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  I saved your script as script.sh and tried to run it with awk -f script.sh and it returned a syntax error with one of these ^ pointing to the equals sign before the empty string.  (In RS="" it was pointing to the =)  Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am using Gawk for windows because I only have windows 7 laptop available.  Thanks again!

Comment: in that case, remove the `-v RS=""` option and put `BEGIN{RS=""}` in the awk script. The windows command prompt is probably messing with it.

Comment: If you want a unixy command on a windows box, check out cygwin.com

Comment: I tried the script again the way you said and it gave the same syntax error and I tried on cygwin and got the same thing.  Maybe it just doesn't work in cygwin or windows?  Anyway, I am going to try and use a windows program to do this.  Thanks for trying to help, I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: If you saved the entire snippet as script.sh you should run it as `sh script.sh` (as opposed to `awk -f script.sh`) because this is a shell script calling awk. The error you mention looks like the way of calling the script is the problem.